# Does vscode editor support .inc file highlight?

Tags: visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

I'm using .inc files in vscode, but I find that vscode does not support .inc files' highlight.Does vscode support inc file syntax highlighting?

[image]

Answer (score 43, accepted):

`.inc` files are used in multiple languages; what language are you using them in?

You can tell VSCode to apply language-specific syntax highlighting by editing the `settings.json` (File > Preferences > Settings) by adding the file extension to the highlighting category.

For example, to highlight `.inc` files as PHP,

```
{
"files.associations": { "*.inc": "php"}
}
```

See [this link](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/vMarch#_editor) for more details.

Comment: Or, File (Code on macOS) > Preferences > Settings > Text Editor > Files > Add Item. Add an item with `*.inc` and `php` as mentioned in this answer.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

version : 1.64.2
File > Preferences > Settings

Answer (score 2):

2018 Update - Visual Studio Code 1.24.1

Its;

```
File > Preferences >  Settings
```

You will get  a dual pane as below ;

```
Default User Settings     || User Settings
"files.associations": {}
```

Copy that over to the User Settings Pane ( right pane ) and paste at the 
bottom ( before the closing parentheses );

```
 ... || User Settings
          "files.associations": {
           "*.inc": "php"
          }
        } // closing parentheses
```